# Why an object is not constructible?

Tags: c++

I have the following code

```
class MyValue
{
    std::any value;
    MyValue(std::any value)
        : value(value)
    {
    }

public:
    using ErrorType = std::string;
    using MaybeMy = std::variant<ErrorType, MyValue>;

    static MaybeMy safeWrap(std::any const &obj) noexcept
    {
        if (std::any_cast<int>(&obj) != nullptr)
            return MyValue(obj);
        else
            return ErrorType("There is some alien type");
    }
    operator std::string() const
    {
        return std::to_string(std::any_cast<int>(value));
    }
    MyValue(MyValue &&) = default;
};

int main()
{
    auto printer = [](auto &&v) { std::cout << std::string(v) << std::endl; };
    MyValue::MaybeMy as[] = {MyValue::safeWrap(10), MyValue::safeWrap("10")};
    for (auto &&v : as)
        std::visit(printer, v);
}
```

But I receive errors related with std::variant -  MyValue is not constructible.
I cannot understand reasons for this.

Why is `MyValue` not constructible? And why is there some restriction to execute the code?

Compiler's output:

```
[build] In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/variant:36,
[build]  from /home/created/Documents/Cpp/gstream_test/main.cpp:8:
[build] /usr/include/c++/9/type_traits: In instantiation of ‘struct std::__and_<std::is_copy_constructible<MyValue>, std::is_constructible<MyValue, const MyValue&> >’:
[build] /usr/include/c++/9/any:181:58:   required by substitution of ‘template<class _ValueType, class _Tp, class _Mgr, typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::is_copy_constructible<_Tp>, std::is_constructible<_Tp, _ValueType&&> >::value, bool>::type <anonymous>, typename std::enable_if<(! std::__is_in_place_type<_Tp>::value), bool>::type <anonymous> > std::any::any(_ValueType&&) [with _ValueType = const MyValue&; _Tp = MyValue; _Mgr = std::any::_Manager_external<MyValue>; typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::is_copy_constructible<_Tp>, std::is_constructible<_Tp, _ValueType&&> >::value, bool>::type <anonymous> = <missing>; typename std::enable_if<(! std::__is_in_place_type<_Tp>::value), bool>::type <anonymous> = <missing>]’
[build] /usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:883:12:   required from ‘struct std::is_constructible<MyValue, const MyValue&>’
[build] /usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:901:12:   required from ‘struct std::__is_copy_constructible_impl<MyValue, true>’
[build] /usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:907:12:   required from ‘struct std::is_copy_constructible<MyValue>’
[build] /usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:2925:25:   required from ‘constexpr const bool std::is_copy_constructible_v<MyValue>’
[build] /usr/include/c++/9/variant:275:5:   required from ‘constexpr const bool std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, MyValue>::_S_copy_ctor’
[build] /usr/include/c++/9/variant:1220:11:   required from ‘class std::variant<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, MyValue>’
[build] /home/created/Documents/Cpp/gstream_test/main.cpp:26:5:   required from here
[build] /usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:131:12: error: incomplete type ‘std::is_copy_constructible<MyValue>’ used in nested name specifier
[build]   131 |     struct __and_<_B1, _B2>
[build]       |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] /usr/include/c++/9/type_traits: In instantiation of ‘struct std::__and_<std::is_copy_constructible<MyValue>, std::__not_<std::is_constructible<MyValue, const MyValue&> >, std::__not_<std::__is_in_place_type<MyValue> > >’:
[build] /usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:150:27:   required from ‘constexpr const bool std::__and_v<std::is_copy_constructible<MyValue>, std::__not_<std::is_constructible<MyValue, const MyValue&> >, std::__not_<std::__is_in_place_type<MyValue> > >’
[build] /usr/include/c++/9/any:192:27:   required by substitution of ‘template<class _ValueType, class _Tp, class _Mgr, typename std::enable_if<__and_v<std::is_copy_constructible<_Tp>, std::__not_<std::is_constructible<_Tp, _ValueType&&> >, std::__not_<std::__is_in_place_type<_Tp> > >, bool>::type <anonymous> > std::any::any(_ValueType&&) [with _ValueType = const MyValue&; _Tp = MyValue; _Mgr = std::any::_Manager_external<MyValue>; typename std::enable_if<__and_v<std::is_copy_constructible<_Tp>, std::__not_<std::is_constructible<_Tp, _ValueType&&> >, std::__not_<std::__is_in_place_type<_Tp> > >, bool>::type <anonymous> = <missing>]’
[build] /usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:883:12:   required from ‘struct std::is_constructible<MyValue, const MyValue&>’
[build] /usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:901:12:   required from ‘struct std::__is_copy_constructible_impl<MyValue, true>’
[build] /usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:907:12:   required from ‘struct std::is_copy_constructible<MyValue>’
[build] /usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:2925:25:   required from ‘constexpr const bool std::is_copy_constructible_v<MyValue>’
[build] /usr/include/c++/9/variant:275:5:   required from ‘constexpr const bool std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, MyValue>::_S_copy_ctor’
[build] /usr/include/c++/9/variant:1220:11:   required from ‘class std::variant<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, MyValue>’
[build] /home/created/Documents/Cpp/gstream_test/main.cpp:26:5:   required from here
[build] /usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:136:12: error: incomplete type ‘std::is_copy_constructible<MyValue>’ used in nested name specifier
[build]   136 |     struct __and_<_B1, _B2, _B3, _Bn...>
[build]       |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] /usr/include/c++/9/type_traits: In instantiation of ‘constexpr const bool std::__and_v<std::is_copy_constructible<MyValue>, std::__not_<std::is_constructible<MyValue, const MyValue&> >, std::__not_<std::__is_in_place_type<MyValue> > >’:
[build] /usr/include/c++/9/any:192:27:   required by substitution of ‘template<class _ValueType, class _Tp, class _Mgr, typename std::enable_if<__and_v<std::is_copy_constructible<_Tp>, std::__not_<std::is_constructible<_Tp, _ValueType&&> >, std::__not_<std::__is_in_place_type<_Tp> > >, bool>::type <anonymous> > std::any::any(_ValueType&&) [with _ValueType = const MyValue&; _Tp = MyValue; _Mgr = std::any::_Manager_external<MyValue>; typename std::enable_if<__and_v<std::is_copy_constructible<_Tp>, std::__not_<std::is_constructible<_Tp, _ValueType&&> >, std::__not_<std::__is_in_place_type<_Tp> > >, bool>::type <anonymous> = <missing>]’
[build] /usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:883:12:   required from ‘struct std::is_constructible<MyValue, const MyValue&>’
[build] /usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:901:12:   required from ‘struct std::__is_copy_constructible_impl<MyValue, true>’
[build] /usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:907:12:   required from ‘struct std::is_copy_constructible<MyValue>’
[build] /usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:2925:25:   required from ‘constexpr const bool std::is_copy_constructible_v<MyValue>’
[build] /usr/include/c++/9/variant:275:5:   required from ‘constexpr const bool std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, MyValue>::_S_copy_ctor’
[build] /usr/include/c++/9/variant:1220:11:   required from ‘class std::variant<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, MyValue>’
[build] /home/created/Documents/Cpp/gstream_test/main.cpp:26:5:   required from here
[build] /usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:150:27: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::__and_<std::is_copy_constructible<MyValue>, std::__not_<std::is_constructible<MyValue, const MyValue&> >, std::__not_<std::__is_in_place_type<MyValue> > >’
[build]   150 |     inline constexpr bool __and_v = __and_<_Bn...>::value;
[build]       |                           ^~~~~~~
```

---

I'm using gcc 9.3

Comment: Please don't just handwave the error, post the actual error message.

Comment: Can't reproduce. [Compiles for me](https://godbolt.org/z/6GG6oc)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik he uses [gcc 9.3](https://godbolt.org/z/GhPns8).

Comment: @MarekR Well, compiles with [gcc 10](https://godbolt.org/z/dxs33M), too. So likely a compiler bug fixed in a later version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a gcc bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90415

It was fixed in gcc 8 and gcc 10+.

The error happens when you have a constructor taking a `std::any`, which instantiates some type traits really early and breaks stuff, and makes a hard error when you try to move your type (since it also considers the implicit conversion to `std::any`)

A workaround is to not have a constructor taking `std::any`, by adding a dummy parameter:

```cpp
    MyValue(int, std::any value)
        : value(value)
    {
    }

    // ...

        return MyValue(0, obj);
```

Or using `std::experimental::any`/`std::experimental::fundamentals_v1::any` instead

Comment: I think somethink like this happens with a returning type `std::variant`. Because if I change it into `MyValue*` [it](https://godbolt.org/z/zq9j3c) is also compiled well.

Comment: @SergeyB `std::variant` tries to move from the temporary you create. Trying to use the move constructor makes the issue occur: https://godbolt.org/z/6nxfYs

Answer (score -1):

The default accessibility for class members is private.  Since your constructor comes before the `public:` declaration, nobody can construct any objects of this class.